"QODBCDriver::record: Unable to allocate handle" Error: ""
In Qt6, the SQL server was connected and the database was successfully opened. However, when using the setTable method of QsqlTableModel, the error "QODBDriver:: record: Unable to allocate handle" appeared.
code:
{
    tabModel = new QSqlTableModel(this, DB);
    tabModel->setTable(QString("Book"));
    if (! tabModel->select()) {
        QMessageBox:: critical (this, "Error message", "Opening database table error, Errormessage:\n"+ tabModel->lastError().text());
        qDebug() << tabModel->lastError().text();
        return;
}

I want to know why this problem occurred.QODBDriver::record: Unable to allocate handle


Could it be that the capitalized table name is causing problems? For capitalized table names, I think you have to call them with quotes. But you probably have to figure out how to escape the quotes so they actually get passed to the driver. It's much better to use lower case names for tables and field names in PostgreSQL

The issue of changing the table name to lowercase still hasn't been resolved.I think the main issue is QODBDriver:: record: Unable to allocate handle

Are you connected to correct database?

I can use QSqlQuery to query, but I cannot use the method in the question
